# Cannot select from database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to select from my MySQL database, from the table Lines. I made it really simple, it should simply show all rows in the database. However I'm getting an error on line 16 (I put an * next to it) that says: "mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource"

```
$con = mysql_connect("...","...","mypass");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  mysql_select_db("dbname", $con);
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Lines");
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) ***************
  { 
  echo $row['Text'];
  echo "<br />";
  } 
  mysql_close($con);
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: what happens when you var_dump `$result`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add mysql_error() after mysql_query() to see if there's any error, I'm guessing table Lines doesn't exist:

```
$con = mysql_connect("copoetry.db.6945202.hostedresource.com","dbname","mypass");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  mysql_select_db("dbname", $con);
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Lines");
  echo mysql_error(); die;
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) ***************
  { 
  echo $row['Text'];
  echo "<br />";
  } 
  mysql_close($con);
```

Answer (score 4):

Lines is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL. Use backticks.

```
SELECT * FROM `Lines`
```

Comment: Thanks, I could have been my whole life and never knew why it didn't work.